# counting attribute value over table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

for every td in a table I have an Data attribute that can have 4 value's (ie 'Dag', 'Avond', 'Nacht' and 'Vrij') I want to count the values in the columns, ie how often there is 'Dag' in a column. The table has a variable number of rows and columns.

I want to use arrays for the different values to count the totals for each value. ie Dag[], Avond[], nacht[] and then for every column add 1 if the value exist in that table cell.

```
 var D = new Array();
 var A = new Array();
 var N = new Array();
 $('#drawTable > tbody').each(function (i) { //for each row
     $(this).each(function (x) {  //for each cell in this row
         var waarde = $(this).attr('data-total');  //get attibute value
         switch (waarde){  //depending on its value
             case 'Dag':
                 D[x] = D[x] + 1;
                 break;
             case 'Avond':
                 A[x] = A[x] + 1;
                 break;
             case 'Nacht':
                 N[x] = N[x] + 1;
                 break;
         }
     });
});
```

my code does not loop trough all rows and cells. i stays at 4 and x stays at 0.
also I have the feeling I should initiate my arrays with 0

Comment: This is not the right approach. The solution is much simpler than what you are doing, but we really need to see the relevant HTML to be able to give you a concise answer. Please edit your question and add the appropriate HTML.

Comment: you also need to post the HTML..

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
var D = new Array;
var A = new Array;
var N = new Array;

$(function () {
    //Get the number of td in a row
    var l = $('#MyTable tr:first td').length;
    //Fill the array x with zero's
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
        D[i] = 0;
        A[i] = 0;
        N[i] = 0;
    }

    $('#MyButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#MyTable tr').each(function () {
            $(this).find('td.tdclass').each(function (i) {
                var waarde = $(this).attr('Data-test');
                //alert(waarde + ' i= ' + i);
                switch (waarde) {
                    case 'Dag':
                        D[i]++;
                        break;
                    case 'Avond':
                        A[i]++;
                        break;
                    case 'Nacht':
                        N[i]++;
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
        alert('Dagdiensten: '+D[0] + ' ' + D[1] + ' Avonddiensten: '+ A[0] + ' ' + A[1] + ' Nachtdiensten: ' + N[0] + ' '+ N[1]);
    });
});
```